# Can postMessage sends more complex objects

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm currently working on a webExtension, and injected the html of my webExtension into an iframe. I want to drag stuff from arbitrary web pages into a droppable area in the iframe, and display them in the droppable area. I have a dragstartListener that uses postMessage to send the HTMLdocument of the element dragged everytime it listens to a dragstart event. But postMessage cannot send objects with methods inside. Are there any alternatives to implement the function? Thank you!

Comment: JSON.stringify/parse ... So yes you can. But that means that you cannot simply pass a function and call it on the other side.

Comment: why dont you implement the function on the Site in the Iframe so you can just "send" the content to the Iframe and then use the function on the other side

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Jonas: I tried using JSON.stringify/parse, but a large portion of the objects became null after being parsed back, since they have methods inside. @Matthias: I'm trying to send the content to the Iframe, but my functions need the HTMLdocument of the element, and it cannot be sent via postMessage.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651977/why-cant-you-stringify-a-function-expression . Basicly you could find all functions in the Elements that you want to stringify and add ``"" +` before it. so it  will be handeled as a string. then you can post it to your iframe

Comment: So with regular Expressions you could do: `string.replace(/function()/gi, "\"\" + function()")`

Comment: @MatthiasGwiozda Thank you for the answer! I tried similar approach through deleting the functions recursively (the document has document inside of it). But the recursion was so deep that it reaches the limit for system stack.

Comment: :O why do you have a document in the document ?

Comment: @MatthiasGwiozda Yeah it's an HTMLDocument so it has the attribute parentNode, which itself is also an HTMLDocument.

Comment: Would it be bad to set this property to null so you can transport it to the iframe?

Comment: @MatthiasGwiozda It is bad since the info are needed in those functions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution: using XMLSerializer.

XML Serializer can actually serialize dom elements into strings. Postmessage can send strings to another window safely.