# TypeScript class to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a class array where the class looks like:

```
class Tag{
    select: string;
    search: string;
}
```

I want to convert it to JSON where it'll probably look like `[{select: "blah", search: "bleh"}, {...}, {...}]`.

Is this possible? Because from the Angular 2 tutorial you can do the opposite with the line:

```
.map((r: Response) => r.json().data as Hero[]);
```

Comment: most things in js are objects so yes

Comment: @madalinivascu would you know any functions?

Comment: a useful question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589880/using-json-stringify-on-custom-class

Comment: That did it, would you like to post an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert an **instance** of this class into a plain old JS object? Or you want to convert an **instance** of this class into a JSON string? Or you want to convert the class itself--what would that mean? Also, note that this question has nothing to do with angular, and very little to do with TypeScript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert javascript objects into json strings using `JSON.stringify()`
Since classes and instances of the classes are objects in javascript you can stringify them as well

Answer (score 6):

You can add a `toJSON()` function in your class. This function gets called automatically when `JSON.stringify()` is called on your class instance

```
class Person{
  constructor(readonly name){}

  toJSON(){
    return {
      firstName: this.name
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you `console.log` you class instance using `JSON.stringify` you will see this result

const person = new Person("Tom");
console.log(JSON.stringify(person));

Output

```
{
  firstName: "Tom"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.stringify()` most thing in `js` are object.

```
class Hero{}
let Heros:Hero[] = JSON.stringify(response.data);
```

so the `Heros`  is the Array you want :)

Comment: thanks, but madalin gave me the answer first so if he make an answer I'll mark it. Still +1

Comment: This is not an answer. Besides it will not even compile.

Comment: stringify() returns a string, how can it be a Hero array?