# Serialize/Stringify javascript object

Tags: javascript, stringify

I would like to serialize/stringify a javascript object that can be passed between browsers as a string using signalr

The signalr portion is working, as i can send and receive chat messages.

This is my simple test rig

```
function UserObject() {
  var _firstName = 't';
  this.getFirstName = function () {
    return _firstName;
  }
  this.setFirstName = function (value) {
    _firstName = value;
  }
}

var userObject = new UserObject();
console.log(userObject.getFirstName());
userObject.setFirstName('tony');
console.log(JSON.stringify(userObject));
console.log("First Name: " + userObject.getFirstName());
```

This is the results that i am receiving.

```
> "t"
> "{}"
> "First Name: tony"
```

Why is the console.log(JSON.stringify(userObject)) failing?
When i can set the value, reset the value and not see the value when i try to view the object.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13589880/1300910

Answer (score 2):

It's failing because you only have private variables.

Here's with public properties.

```js
function UserObject() {
  var _firstName = 't';
  this.getFirstName = function () {
    return this.firstName || _firstName;
  }
  this.setFirstName = function (value) {
    this.firstName = value;
  }
}

var userObject = new UserObject();
console.log(userObject.getFirstName());
userObject.setFirstName('tony');
console.log(JSON.stringify(userObject));
console.log("First Name: " + userObject.getFirstName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `UserObject` doesn't have any public field to serialize.

Try to assign to `this.firstName` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your value is stored in `_firstName`, which is a local variable in the `UserObject` function. It's not stored in the object, so serializing the object won't show it.

The only thing stored in your object is two functions (`getFirstName`, `setFirstName`), but JSON can't represent functions.

That's why the JSON result shows an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i went with....

```
    var UserObject = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    };
    UserObject.firstName = 'tony';
    var myObjStr = JSON.stringify(UserObject);
    console.log(myObjStr);
    var uo = JSON.parse(myObjStr);
    console.log(uo);
```