# How can I write a class instance to a string in JS?

Tags: javascript, json, class, stringify

I have a game written in JavaScript that stores lots of game related data in objects. For example, the map of the world is written in a class like this:

```
const theMap = new GameMap();

class GameMap() {
    constructor() {
        this.rooms = [];
    }
    addRoom(name) {
        this.rooms.push(name);
    }
}
```

I want to store the variable `theMap`in a string so I can write it to a file. I can use `JSON.stringify(theMap)` to convert it to JSON, but it removes the methods. If I were to convert the JSON back to an object, I couldn't use `addRoom` on it anymore. Is there a way to preserve those methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using JSON.stringify on custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589880/using-json-stringify-on-custom-class)

Comment: Why do you need to store logic in your GameMap? Surely the data is the only thing that changes between instances of the game.

Comment: Does not make sense to stringinfy the class. Make a save method that outputs data in some format. And on init, you can look for the data and import it back in.

Comment: I think you're looking for serialization

Comment: Actually, [`JSON.stringify()` can be configured to store functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875630/javascript-save-object-with-methods-as-a-string/40876342#40876342).