# how to use child_process.fork in meteor

Tags: meteor

I test the code in meteor .There are some errors.

/server/lib/Test.js

```
Test = {
    say:function(){
        console.log("hello world");
    }
}
```

/server/main.js

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    Test.say();  //work well 
    var path = Npm.require('path');
    var base = path.resolve('.');
    var n = Npm.require('child_process').fork(base+"/app/server/children.js");
    n.on('message', function(m) {
      console.log('PARENT got message:', m);
    });
    n.send({ hello: 'world' });
});
```

/server/children.js

```
process.on('message', function(m) {
  Test.say();   //throw a error . The Test is undefined
  console.log('CHILD got message:', m);
  process.send({name:"ABC"});
});

process.send({ foo: 'bar' });
```

errors:

```
I20131223-16:34:44.717(8)? hello world
W20131223-16:34:44.784(8)? (STDERR) /home/ec/workspace/meteor/testChildrenProcess/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/server/children.js:2
W20131223-16:34:44.784(8)? (STDERR)   Test.say();
W20131223-16:34:44.785(8)? (STDERR)   ^
W20131223-16:34:44.785(8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Test is not defined
W20131223-16:34:44.787(8)? (STDERR)     at process. (/home/ec/workspace/meteor/testChildrenProcess/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/server/children.js:2:3)
W20131223-16:34:44.788(8)? (STDERR)     at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
W20131223-16:34:44.788(8)? (STDERR)     at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
W20131223-16:34:44.788(8)? (STDERR)     at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:345:11)
```

The Test Object is undefined in "/app/server/children.js"  bu it's normal in main.js.
Why?  Have I forgotten anything? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are scoped. While in Meteor `Test` would be available to the other files in your meteor project they are not available to Npm modules/stuff required by `Npm.require`.

The `children.js` would be in a different namespace to your `main.js` file. To access the `Test` variable in it you would need to pass it a param or as a message.

Comment: Thanks for input. but when I ```n.send({ hello: 'world',Test:Test });``` in ```Meteor.startup```. in children.js can't get function ```say```

Comment: Not very sure of the types of data you can pass, you can pass arguments but not sure about entire objects because its a separate process. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368436/fork-a-child-process-and-inject-dependency