# Why can Errors not be stringified?

Tags: javascript

Why can Errors not be stringified?

```
JSON.stringify(new ReferenceError('foo')); // {}
```

When for example, Date does something more useful:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date()); // "2015-04-01T10:23:24.749Z"
```

Comment: Have a look at
[avascript-stringify-object-including-members-of-type-function][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685703/javascript-stringify-object-including-members-of-type-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript `Error` objects are not [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable). You can verify this easily:

```
new Error('Test').propertyIsEnumerable('message');
// -> false
```

You can however define your own `toJSON` function on the error Object:

```
Object.defineProperty(Error.prototype, 'toJSON', {
    value: function () {
        return {value: "Test"};
    },
    configurable: true
});

JSON.stringify(new Error());
-> "{value: "Test"}"
```